# Keyboard not showing up with scrollView in webView android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a webView inside a scrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_header"
        />

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <WebView 
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />   

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

But it won't let me get keyboard when I click on form field or edit box in webView like login fields etc

I have tried removing scrollView . perhaps its because once the values are recorded that is I made the webView "Remember" those fields and that is why the keyboard is not showing? How can I fix this

What should I do :(

Comment: do you have tested it on any android device instead of the emulator.

Comment: I am working on s2.... Probably ScrollViw won't let it getting focus perhaps? It started when i added scrollView and I can't remove scrollView

Comment: what is the use of RelativeLayout here .lol..can you not use textview or other thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please check this .read from here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

```
android:windowSoftInputMode=["stateUnspecified",
                                       "stateUnchanged", "stateHidden",
                                       "stateAlwaysHidden", "stateVisible",
                                       "stateAlwaysVisible", "adjustUnspecified",
                                       "adjustResize", "adjustPan"] >   

android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
```

try this

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

for hiding

```
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ed.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

to showing

```
imm.showSoftInput(ed, 0);
```

Comment: the error came when I clicked on remember. I had to uninstall app to make it work. hOW CAn i fix this

Answer (score 1):

In the android manifest in the activity tag, see to it you have given this

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
```

your code might have

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

check it out and let me know.

Comment: Didn't work, I don't have keyboard hidden but i added the above one. The problem started when I added scrollView and I can't remove scrollView otherwise WebView won't show its contents